# Should there be more strict rules in order to ask a Question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

Is it me or the Questions in SO are getting extremely overwhelmed?

And the bad thing (in my opinion ) is that the most of the Qs are bad in every sense.

This fact can have serious drawbacks. if in case I want to search for particular pattern Q it will result in lots of answers most of which will be possibly out of content or crap.

If this are true (and I am not me saying crap) should there be more strict rules where someone tries to address a Question?

Comment: You might like to provide an example of this, though I know of a few who share the same sentiment as you.

Comment: We have several in place already.  Do you have something specific you'd like to see added?  Saying in general, "add more filters" doesn't really help much.  If we knew of another good way to filter out only bad questions we'd do it.

Comment: @Servy the rule of checking the Qs title and evaluating if a similar exists is sth very practical and well formed..However in practise , if am not mistaken the system permits the user to make the Q inspite the fact that the title is similar to another  Q already made

Comment: this rule I think could be upgraded

Comment: @apomene And I'm personally fine with that.  Sometimes the one sentance summary of a question can be very similar to another despite the details being quite a bit different.  It's a red flag, but one with quite a few false positives.  Sounds like it's working as I'd prefer now.

Comment: @Servy You are quite true. It is very difficult to distinguish and cut off just from the title when a one Q differs from another most of the times, it would require a very smart AI

Comment: Do you have any concrete suggestion how to improve it?

Comment: If it find matching titles permit the user to insert body and afterwards compare the Qs body with the already founded titles Qs body asked to see the level of agreement.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume for a moment that your theory is correct. Someone should be asking "what does this error code 12345 mean" and instead they ask "ridiculous response from compiler". They do include enough code that somebody can guess what they mean, and one of the answers is "that error code, 12345, means blah blah blah and you can correct it by something something something."

Over time, someone will fix the question, but even if no-one did, if you search "what does this error code 12345 mean?" you will find this question, because your search words are in the answer!

Now if you're worried that people are asking questions that are total crap, and the answers to those questions are somehow going to crowd out the good answers you want to find, so there should be some way to prevent anyone from answering crap questions - congratulations, you just invented [closing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)! You can already flag questions that should be closed, and soon, you will have [enough rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) to vote to close. This prevents the situation you're worried about.